# Can YouTube videos be downloaded with subtitles for offline viewing using the app?

Tags: youtube

I noticed that when I download a video in the YouTube app for offline viewing, subtitles are not included.

What do I need to do so that I can see subtitles while viewing a video offline?

Answer (score 1):

With youtube-dl you can download all available subtitles from video. More details you can find [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme).

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'TubeMate' app. I personally like it very much as when I copy the link of any video from my YouTube app, it automatically detects it and shows a icon, by clicking on which you can directly reach the TubeMate app. 
If the video has subtitles, it will automatically download it, and also the download speed is very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have YouTube Premium, start watching the video you want to download and turn on captions. Now when you start the download it should also download the subtitles.